# React - How to pass props to a component passed as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component (React v15.5.4) that you can pass other components to:

```
class CustomForm extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.props.component}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I have a different component that uses it:

```
class SomeContainer extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    let someObjectVariable = {someProperty: 'someValue'};
    return (
      <CustomForm 
         component={<SomeInnerComponent someProp={'someInnerComponentOwnProp'}/>}
         object={someObjectVariable}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Everything renders fine, but I want to pass **someObjectVariable** prop to the child component inside **CustomForm** (in this case that'll be **SomeInnerComponent**), since in the actual code you can pass several components to it instead of just one like the example.

Mind you, I also need to pass **SomeInnerComponent** its own props.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: which one do you refer when you said child component CustomForm or SomeInnerComponent?

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas SomeInnerComponent. I'll edit my question

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that's one way. But like I said, I might pass an array of several components, and I don't want to do that for each one

Comment: If you are going to pass a many components with a shared value won't be better if you use `context`? In this way you'll avoid to recreate the components over and over again

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

Like this:

```
class CustomForm extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.component,{ customProps: this.props.object })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working Code:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <Child a={1} comp={<GChild/>} />
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {b: 1};
    this.updateB = this.updateB.bind(this);
  }
  
  updateB(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({b: prevState.b+1}))
  }
  
  render(){
    var Comp = this.props.comp;
    return (
      <div>
        {React.cloneElement(Comp, {b: this.state.b})}
        <button onClick={this.updateB}>Click to update b</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const GChild = props => <div>{JSON.stringify(props)}</div>;
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container' />
```

Comment: I can't use option 2 because I need to pass SomeInnerComponent its own props. I'll edit to question to make that clear. I'll try 1 though

Comment: oh ok, if you want to use the 2nd approach, then you can do one thing. Pass all those props values to CustomForm then from CustomForm you can pass to SomeInnerComponent.

Comment: Will child props passed from CustomForm be updated if value changes on CustomFor? doesn't look like it does

Comment: It does, there was something wrong with my code. So if you just leave option 1, I can check this as the correct answer. And thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 6):

You can do in the same as you did for `SomeInnerComponent`.

Just pass named props.

Inside `CustomForm`,

```
render() {

  const MyComponent = this.props.component; //stored it in some variable

    return (
      <div> 
         <MyComponent customProps = {this.props.object} /> //access object here and passed it or passed individual props
      </div>
    );
  }
```

EDIT :

Please find the [`working demo here`](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmqwwnrnk9).

Comment: Got this error message when I tried this approach: "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object"

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori It should be work.I think inside . of your `SomeInnerComponent ` or `CustomForm ` you are trying display an object that why you getting such error.Please see updated DEMO codedandbox

Comment: As I mentioned with keyword `working demo here`. replace `myComponent and  myComponent ` with `component and SomeInnerComponent ` resp.  :D

Comment: This works if you pass `someInnerComponent=SomeInnerComponent` i.e. you are *passing a class*, but not if you pass `someInnerComponent={<SomeInnerComponent someProp={'someInnerComponentOwnProp'}/>}` i.e. *passinig an object*, which is what the question was asking about. With this technique you have no way to set some props at the top level and some more at the mid-level container, you have to set them all in the mid-level container.

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of options to achieve what your asking.

```
class SomeContainer extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
   let someObjectVariable = {someProperty: 'someValue'};
    return (
      <CustomForm 
       component={<SomeInnerComponent propFromParent={someObjectVariable}/>}
       object={someObjectVariable}
      />
    );
  }
```

}

Or you can clone the component prop and apply the new props as Mayank said. In your case

```
class CustomForm extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.component,
           {propFromParent:this.props.someObjectVariable})}
      </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-overrides](https://github.com/ilyalesik/react-overrides) for this.
Create CustomForm:

```
import o from "react-overrides";

const InnerComponent = () => null; // default

class CustomForm extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <InnerComponent {...o} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Pass props and component of `InnerComponent` at `overrides` prop:

```
class SomeContainer extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    let someObjectVariable = {someProperty: 'someValue'};
    return (
      <CustomForm 
         object={someObjectVariable}
         overrides={{
             InnerComponent: {
                 component: SomeInnerComponent,
                 props: {
                     someProp: 'someInnerComponentOwnProp'
                 }
             }
         }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextField place={"India"}> </TextField>
```

and in your component TextField

```
class TextField extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input />
                <button> {this.props.place} </button>
            </div>
        )
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are trying to achieve is something like this you have to pass your `InnerComponent` as an arrow function `() =>` ..

```
class SomeContainer extends React.Component {   ...   render() {
    let someObjectVariable = {someProperty: 'someValue'};
    return (
      <CustomForm 
         component={() => <SomeInnerComponent someProp={'someInnerComponentOwnProp'}/>}
         object={someObjectVariable}
      />
    );   } }
```