# Passing prop into react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need some help to solve an interesting use case that I am working right now.

In a component I am rendering another component which is passed as a prop, it works fine. But now I need to send a prop to that component, as I don't have any JSX , I don't know how to pass the prop, should I use bind? The other component is a regular es6 class extending from React.Component.

this is the code:

```
switch (inputType) {
  case 'textarea': return (
    <div className={this.styles.txtArea}>
      <textarea
        className="input" onChange={this.onInputChanged}
        value={this.node.value ? this.node.value : ''}
      />
      {
        this.state.validationError
        ? <p className={this.styles.error}>{errorText || defaultErrorMsg}</p>
        : null
      }
    </div>);
  // case 'select': return (
  //   <select className={this.styles.select} onChange={this.onInputChanged}>
  //     {this.state.currField.input.options.map((option, index) =>
  //       <option value={option.value} key={index}>{option.name}</option>)}
  //   </select>);
  case 'select': return this.props.valueSelector;
```

So basically I need to pass a prop to valueSelector, how do I do it?

And the valueSelector that I send as a prop is:

```
<ValueSelector key="valueSelector" field={this.state.selectedField || queryBuilderFields[0].name}/>
```

So, once I have the valueSelector as a javascript object, I need to set the prop "field". No way to do that?

Comment: By passing props, if you mean your custom props. You can't, unless you make a copy of it in your repo. Bind will not help. Bind changes context. You need to send property to a JSX element.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the valueSelector, this is the component that I get, and I need to pass the prop "field". I really need to copy paste the code into that repo?, Is it really not possible to pass a prop into a component that is being passed as a prop? We can only send props using JSX?

Comment: check `React.cloneElement` [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919320/react-how-to-pass-props-to-a-component-passed-as-prop)

Comment: @MayankShukla Cloning the element worked for me, thanks!. Should you put it as an answer instead of a comment?