# Invoking child methods with Function Components and Hooks in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to switch from using Class Components to Function Components and hooks in ReactJS. I have created a simple program to illustrate what I am trying to do.

This is a child component, which has a name and a value:

```
function Child(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

  function increment() { setValue(value + 1) }

  return (<div>Child ({props.name}): {value}</div>)
}
```

The child component would be passed to a parent, which has its own value, and when this value is decremented, the value of the child should increment:

```
function Parent(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10)

  function decrement() { setValue(value - 1) }

  return (<div>
    <div>Parent: {value}</div>
    <button onClick={decrement}>Pass from parent to child</button>
    {props.child}
  </div>)
}
```

The child is passed to the parent the application level (in theory, children can be switched dynamically, but to simplify here we set one of two):

```
function Application(props) {
  const child1 = <Child name="Alice" />
  const child2 = <Child name="Bob" />
  const child = props.option == "Alice" ? child1 : child2

  return (<Parent child={child} />)
}
```

Now what I need here is that when the parent's value is decremented, the child's value should increment. In React, you don't directly call a child component's method from the parent, so I am looking for a way to achieve this that will also allow me to change the child component as shown in the code.

If you run the code pen below this will make sense.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/reactnoob69/pen/KKZbqEp)

Comment: You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you saying you want to execute `increment` - currently defined in the Child component - in the parent? Well you can't, state is internal to a component, deliberately inaccessible from outside - only props (which can include functions) form the "public interface" of a component. It's not clear why you have separate state in parent and child, or what you're actually trying to illustrate. Do you perhaps have a more realistic example?

Comment: @Aaron Context is not for global state only

Comment: How did you solve this with class components?

Comment: see: [React - How to pass props to a component passed as prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919320/react-how-to-pass-props-to-a-component-passed-as-prop) (And contrary to  @RobinZigmond s comment you can pass functions back to a parent using a `ref`, it's just a bit of an anti-pattern)

Comment: @Aaron Still: two components, at different nesting levels. Nothing wrong with putting both in a context provider here.

Comment: I agree that you should refactor to use `context` or properly lift state, but to get your pattern working you can use the linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919320/react-how-to-pass-props-to-a-component-passed-as-prop) solution. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-props-to-component-as-prop-42e4n6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - How to pass props to a component passed as prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919320/react-how-to-pass-props-to-a-component-passed-as-prop)

Comment: It will get voted as duplicate by the community, but you're free to accept the answer regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for

```
    const { useState } = React;

function Parent(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10)
  
  const [childValue, setChildValue] = useState(0)
  
  function changeValue(){
    setValue(value-1);
    setChildValue(childValue + 1);
    
  }
  
  return (<div>
    <div>Parent: {value}</div>
    <button onClick={changeValue}>Pass from parent to child</button>
    <Child name={props.option} value={childValue} /> 
  </div>)
}

function Child(props) {
  return (<div>Child ({props.name}): {props.value}</div>)
}

function Application(props) {
  // Child component is decided by the Application component and can change at any time
  
  return (<Parent option={props.option} />)
}
```

Instead of passing child component from application component pass from Parent component.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Otherwise known as `lifting state up`